# Saber qual índice dos valores do array dá "match" com variável

Tags: javascript, json

Eu tenho dois arrays JSON no JavaScript e os dois estão assim.

Primeiro array:

```
[""Amarelo"", ""Amarelo"", ""Amarelo"", ""Preto"", ""Preto"", ""Preto""]
```

Segundo array:

```
[""Pequeno"", ""Médio"", ""Grande"", ""Pequeno"", ""Médio"", ""Grande""]
```

E eu posso ter duas variáveis que mudam mediante clique que podem ser, por exemplo "amarelo" e "médio".

A questão é: como faço para saber o índice de quando os valores das variáveis batem com os dos arrays?

Olhando assim eu sei que o índice que dá "match" é 1, mas como faço para que o JavaScript descubra isso por si só?

Mediante esse valor índice descoberto eu vou poder chamar o resto do conteúdo dinamicamente.

Alguém pode sugerir um norte para mim?

Comment: você poderia fazer um "for" para percorrer os arrays.

Comment: Sim, imagino que seja esse o caminho, mas eu não tive uma ideia de como seria a lógica para tal ou como estruturar essa ação. Faria um for para cada array? Ou ia buscar isso num while? Ainda não tive a sacada. :(

Comment: As duas arrays sempre têm o mesmo comprimento?

Comment: Sim, as duas tem o mesmo comprimento.

Answer (score 2):

Se as duas arrays têm sempre o mesmo tamanho, faça um loop com contador baseado numa delas, e dentro verifique o valor das duas. Por exemplo:

```js
var cores = ["Amarelo", "Amarelo", "Amarelo", "Preto", "Preto", "Preto"];
var tamanhos = ["Pequeno", "Médio", "Grande", "Pequeno", "Médio", "Grande"];

var corEsperada = 'Amarelo';
var tamanhoEsperado = 'Médio';

for(var i=0; i<cores.length; i++) {
    if(cores[i] === corEsperada && tamanhos[i] === tamanhoEsperado) {
        alert('Encontrado o par ' + corEsperada + '/' + tamanhoEsperado + ' na posição ' + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado bfavaretto, no fim era exatamente isso! Agradeço pela ideia. Abraços

Answer (score 0):

Proposta:

```js
var cores = [ 'amarelo', 'amarelo', 'preto', 'azul' ];
var corProcurada = 'preto';
var indice;

alert((indice = cores.indexOf(corProcurada)) > -1 ? indice + 1 : 'nao achei'); // 3
```

Fonte: [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: Boa Marcelo. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a função `indexOf()`. No seu caso ficaria assim:

```
var array1 = ["Amarelo", "Amarelo", "Amarelo", "Preto", "Preto", "Preto"];
var variavel1 = "Amarelo";
var index1 = array1.indexOf(variavel1);
```

`index1` vai ser o valor do primeiro elemento igual a "Amarelo", 1 no caso. Se ele não encontrar, retorna -1.

Answer (score 0):

Outra solução em ES6 seria utilizar o método [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). Assim você interrompe o laço assim que a condição for satisfeita:

> O método some() testa se alguns dos elementos no array passam no teste implementado pela função atribuída.

```js
const cores = ['Amarelo', 'Amarelo', 'Amarelo', 'Preto', 'Preto', 'Preto']
const tamanhos = ['Pequeno', 'Médio', 'Grande', 'Pequeno', 'Médio', 'Grande']

const corUsuario = (corUsr) => corUsr === 'Preto'
const tamUsuario = (tamUsr) => tamUsr === 'Grande'

cores.some((cor, i) => {
  if (corUsuario(cor) && tamUsuario(tamanhos[i])) {
    console.log(`produto disponivel: cor ${cor}, tamanho ${tamanhos[i]} no índice ${i}`)
  }
})
```